# Paypal Recurring Payment without paypal account

Tags: php, paypal

Sorry if someone else asked the same question, but i read some posts and i can't figure out what i need to do it.

I'm using the php api to make a paypal express checkout and create a recurring payment profile, but i'd like do it without a paypal account request.

I need a paypal pro? My business account is in Italy, is this features available in this country?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to make a payment from a PayPal account (Payer), to a Payee without a PayPal account? e.g. directly to their Bank Account.  I'm looking to do the same thing.  I know the reverse is possible. e.g. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/paypal/

Answer (score 0):

Recurring Payment with Credit Card is called as DPRP (Direct Payment Recurring Payment)in PayPal, where this function is only available with Website Payments Pro that is available in US, UK and Canada.

In Italy we have the PayPal PRO (with Hosted Sole Solution (HSS)) however the function of DPRP is not included. SO you can't use DPRP.